# How filter array of object with another array of object and get difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I worried how I can filter array of object with another array of object and get items which not have on first array of object

For example:

```
let firstData = [
    {
        name: 'A',
        title: 'A'
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        title: 'B'
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        title: 'C'
    }
]


let secondData = [
    {
        name: 'B',
        title: 'B'
    }
]
```

I want to get item's which not have in each array of object in this case name: A and name: C

eg how compare them with name property?

Comment: write out the output you want, what you're asking is unclear

Comment: I think there is clear question. I wan't to get items which no have in two array of objects too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try more general: firstData without secondData (left) PLUS secondData without firstData (right)

```
let left  = firstData.filter(x=> !secondData.find(y=> x.name==y.name));
let right = secondData.filter(x=> !firstData.find(y=> x.name==y.name));
let result = left.concat(right);
```

```js
let firstData = [
    {
        name: 'A',
        title: 'A'
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        title: 'B'
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        title: 'C'
    }
]


let secondData = [
    {
        name: 'B',
        title: 'B'
    },
    
    {
        name: 'D',
        title: 'D'
    }
]

let left  = firstData.filter(x=> !secondData.find(y=> x.name==y.name));
let right = secondData.filter(x=> !firstData.find(y=> x.name==y.name));
let result = left.concat(right);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the first array and check if [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the second array has an object with the same `name` property :

```js
let firstData = [
  {
    name: "A",
    title: "A"
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    title: "B"
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    title: "C"
  }
];

let secondData = [
  {
    name: "B",
    title: "B"
  }
];

const result = firstData.filter(
  ({ name }) => secondData.some(({ name: secondName }) => secondName !== name)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
const filteredElements = firstData.reduce((acc, firstElement) => {
    for(let secondElement of secondData) {

        for(let firstProperty in firstElement) // Does the first element have a value that doesn't exist in the second element?
            if(!secondElement.hasOwnProperty(firstProperty) || secondElement[firstProperty] !== firstElement[firstProperty])
                return acc.concat(firstElement)

        for(let secondProperty in secondElement) // Does the second element have a value that doesn't exist in the first element?
            if(!firstElement.hasOwnProperty(secondProperty) || firstElement[secondProperty] !== secondElement[secondProperty])
                return acc.concat(firstElement)

        return acc // No differing values means this element exists in the second object, so we ignore it       
    }


    return acc.concat(firstElement)
}, [])

console.log(filteredElements) // A and C
```

Edit: this would compare all values in both objects and look for a difference. If you wish to compare only a specific value, you may set `firstProperty` and `secondProperty` to your desired fields' names.

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith) is the easiest way to archive it:

```
_.differenceWith(firstData,secondData, (left, right) => left.name === right.name)
```

```js
let firstData = [
  {
    name: "A",
    title: "A"
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    title: "B"
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    title: "C"
  }
];

let secondData = [
  {
    name: "B",
    title: "B"
  }
];
console.log(
  _.differenceWith(firstData,secondData, (left, right) => left.name === right.name)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's return empty array

Comment: I just add the snippet for testing

Answer (score 0):

**Two Array Compare**

> Compare the two array with all data like Name & Title

```
    let firstData = [
    {
        name: 'A',
        title: 'A'
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        title: 'F'
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        title: 'C'
    }
];

let secondData = [
    {
        name: 'B',
        title: 'B'
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        title: 'C'
    },
    {
        name: 'D',
        title: 'D'
    }
];

var First = firstData.filter(item => !secondData.find(e => item.name == e.name && item.title == e.title));

var Second  = secondData.filter(item => !firstData.find(e => item.name == e.name && item.title == e.title));

let result = First.concat(Second);

console.log(result);

//output

// Array(5)
// 0: {name: "A", title: "A"}
// 1: {name: "B", title: "F"}
// 2: {name: "B", title: "B"}
// 3: {name: "D", title: "D"}
// length: 4
```

[Source Code](https://codepen.io/awadhesh786/pen/oNvBroV)

```js
let firstData = [
    {
        name: 'Apple',
        title: 'Apple'
    },
    {
        name: 'Banana',
        title: 'Fruits'
    },
    {
        name: 'Cat',
        title: 'Cat'
    }
];

let secondData = [
    {
        name: 'Banana',
        title: 'Banana'
    },
    {
        name: 'Cat',
        title: 'Cat'
    },
    {
        name: 'Dog',
        title: 'Dog'
    }
];

var First = firstData.filter(item => !secondData.find(e => item.name == e.name && item.title == e.title));

var Second  = secondData.filter(item => !firstData.find(e => item.name == e.name && item.title == e.title));

let result = First.concat(Second);

console.log(result);



//Output

// (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
// 0: {name: "Apple", title: "Apple"}
// 1: {name: "Banana", title: "Fruits"}
// 2: {name: "Banana", title: "Banana"}
// 3: {name: "Dog", title: "Dog"}
// length: 4
```